# Redirct is not working on first time login reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have pasted the code which is used for log in my application. Even though the login is successful, the page is not redirecting When login on the first time. After that its working properly. On the first time, the response is goes to catch block also even the response is 200. How to solve this issue.

```
 export function login(loginForm){
    return function(dispatch) {

        axios.post(config.api.url + 'public/signin', { "email": loginForm.email, "password" :  loginForm.password})
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_USER' });

                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                hashHistory.push('/');
                location.reload();

            })
            .catch(response => {
                dispatch(authError(response.response.data.error));
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    };

this.context.router.push('/');
```